# Creating globally available map

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, architecture

I am working on an hospital application where i need to show blood group in every second page in drop down and getting values from them to the db tables
since blood group are not frequent changing entity so we are planning to create a map with key value pair and make available this map throughout application in order to avid creation of same map multiple time

my question is what can be the best way to achieve this.some of the quick options coming to my mind are

1. Create a map at application start up and place it in application context
2. Create a utility class which read a property file and fill map with these values or   simply create map with exisitng blood type.

but i am not sure how effective these options are as site will have to handle a good amount to user hits in near future.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a utility class that loads these values on system startup or load values when the class loads. Creating a class this way would give few advantages:

- You can test this class and its functionality by writing test cases for this class. (Check if things are loading properly etc)
- This makes you less dependent on the context and how the context works. Makes your application less troublesome to move if you, for some reason, need to change application server.
- Code becomes more readable (`BloodGroupUtils.getAll()` compared to    `Application.getContext().get("bloodGroups");` or something similar.)

On Performance, this may be a bit faster. Not necessarily though ( we would need to check several other system usage/parameters to come to that conclusion.)

Comment: The map in the application context would be loaded in the same way the static class is--the testability of that wouldn't be affected. Every application server gets access to the app context in the same way; it's part of the spec.

Comment: what i meant was, testing the class would be trivial. Testing static classes and methods are problematic, isn't it?

Comment: Testing static classes is no more difficult than anything else. Testing code that *uses* static classes is more difficult and is one main reason we use DI/IoC--`BloodGroupUtils.getAll()` just uses a *different* static class. The code that uses the *map itself* should be decoupled from the mechanism that *retrieves* the map.

Comment: +1 for raising the issue regarding the code that uses the map; I think separating *how* something is created and/or accessed from the code that uses it is very important.

Comment: @RaviBhatt what you mean by the term class loads as in my case i will be using this utility class in my Actions so when my action get called should i put a call to this utility class inside 'action execute method' or what?

Comment: yes, any of your classes that need to get a list of blood group should call this utility class' method. Now your util class needs to load the list at system startup.

Comment: how exactly i can read files on system start-up.any pointer in this regard will be helpful as i am new to web-applications

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the values from a static class or the application context will have essentially the same performance. The static class might be trivially faster as you don't have to get the map out of the application context, but I can't imagine it'd be worth worrying about.

Comment: @user702325 Take note of the comments between myself and Ravi; it brought a good point about keeping the code that *uses* the map decoupled from the mechanism that *retrieves* the map, whether from a static class, from the application context, or from anywhere else.